# Read the configuration file located at ~/.ssh

Tags: swift, macos, file

I need to read the users git ssh configuration file.

Let's consider the following config file:

```
#user1 account
Host github.com-james #Name james
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-user1
   IdentitiesOnly yes

#user2 account
Host github.com-john #Name john
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-user2
   IdentitiesOnly yes
```

I have to read it to get the final result: `["james","john"]`

That would be the hostnames for github.

Can you give me a hand how can I read the configuration file of the `ssh keys`?

Comment: Could you clarify what the problem is with reading this file? Where are you stuck?

Comment: As an aside, `#Name james` is not a comment; both `#Name` and `james` are now valid aliases equivalent to `github.com-james`.

Comment: It looks like a pretty simple file format, so you might not need to use a dedicated parsing library for it. You can read the whole file, split it apart into lines, and filter it to only keep lines that start with `Host`. Then you can split those lines on spaces, and discard the first two components, only keeping `["#Name", "john']`,etc.

Comment: This is not a "git ssh configuration file", it's just an "ssh configuration file". (I snipped [tag:git] but you might want to add [tag:ssh].)